# Delaying element movement triggered by mouse move event, creating smooth animation

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, sveltekit

I want to create a smooth, slightly delayed DIV element movement in reaction to mouse movement on a web page.
An example is here https://www.andreasantonsson.dev/

When you move mouse, background images slightly react in a smooth fashion.

What I have currently is following code

```
<script lang="ts">
    let tilt = 'perspective: 900px';

    function calculateTilt(e: MouseEvent & { currentTarget: Window }): void {
        const halfWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.5;
        const halfHeigth = window.innerHeight * 0.5;
        const xOffset = halfWidth - e.clientX;
        const yOffset = halfHeigth - e.clientY;
        const multiplier = 0.05;

        tilt = `perspective:900px; transform: translateX(${xOffset * multiplier}px) translateY(${
            yOffset * multiplier
        }px)`;
    }
</script>

<svelte:window on:mousemove={calculateTilt} />
<div class="relative">
    <div class="grid grid-rows-4 gap-y-32">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full">
            <div class="w-full h-full transition-transform duration-1000 ease-out" style={tilt}>
                <div
                    class="bg-[url(roni.png)] bg-contain bg-center max-w-screen-xl h-full ml-auto mr-auto sepia brightness-75"
                    style="transform-style:preserve-3d; transform: rotateY(-3.5deg) rotateX(-3deg) rotateZ(-1.2deg) translateZ(-190px);"
                />
            </div>

            <h1 class="font-dahlia text-9xl absolute font-bold text-[#fffff]">Urheilija</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Without any animation, this will perfectly work to create desired tilt on DIV element.
What I cant get to work well is how to this tilt to have a smooth and slightly delayed reaction to mouse movement.

What I tried to do was to add transition-transform on the div with 1000ms time and ease-out properties

```
<div class="w-full h-full transition-transform duration-1000 ease-out" style={tilt}>
```

This gets me somewhat close, but problem is that animation get´s sometimes glitchy and jerky. How should I approach this to get what I want?
Is it supposed to work with transition? If yes, what should I do to smooth it out? If not, what other approach should I take to make it work?

A pseudocode style answer would be awesome as well to get my in the right direction. Im using Sveltekit with Skeleton and TailwindCSS.

Answer (score 0):

So I realized that if you process every mousemove event its becomes such a massive event volume wise. This can use a lot of computer resources and become jerky. As a result I added throttling to mousemove and everything is fine!

```
function throttleMouseMove(e: MouseEvent & { currentTarget: Window }): void {
        if (!isMouseFiring) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                calculateTilt(e);
                isMouseFiring = false;
            }, 50);
        }
        isMouseFiring = true;
    }
```